# I Get Error when i add Icon Using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am Working on a react project and used icon of material UI

First I installed Both Core and Icon Using NPM

Second I Import Icon from Material UI No Errors Until Now

Third I Used Icon using  and get an error it Happens in every single Project

Comment: Show us your code where you're importing the icon.

Comment: import looks fine. Show the code where it is being used,

Comment: Make a try and delete your node_modules and package_lock file and install everything again, errors like that can start to happen when you have the same package more then one time on your project.